# Extract the key/value pair from all blocks of JSON Array and then append it as new key/value pair in each block of JSON Array using BASH and JQ

Tags: arrays, json, bash, shell, jq

I am trying to create a script that extracts a few key/value from all the blocks of an array and then run another shell script using that value to generate a new value and then append that new key/value in all the blocks respectively.

for e.g,

serverdetails.json file

```
{
  "server_details": [
    {
      "seqNo": "01",
      "storage": "IBM",
      "datastore": "IDS-NR02",
      "cpu": 4,
      "site": "SGDC",
      "servertype": "Virtual Machine",
      "location": "Serangoon",
      "operatingsystem": "Linux",
      "systemcode": "BOC",
      "ram": 64,
      "databasesoftware": "MSSQL 2016",
      "usagetype": "Database Server",
      "environment": "Production_WithCustData",
      "domain": "DAPAC",
      "IPAddress": "10.117.254.25",
      "DNS": "10.118.76.34",
      "Gateway": "10.118.76.1",
      "drives": [
        {
          "C": "100"
        },
        {
          "D": "50"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "seqNo": "02",
      "storage": "HITACHI",
      "datastore": "HDS-NR02",
      "cpu": 4,
      "site": "SGDR",
      "servertype": "Virtual Machine",
      "location": "DRC",
      "operatingsystem": "Windows",
      "systemcode": "WOC",
      "ram": 64,
      "databasesoftware": "NA",
      "usagetype": "Web Server",
      "environment": "Production_NonCustData",
      "domain": "EDAPAC",
      "IPAddress": "10.117.254.26",
      "DNS": "10.118.76.34",
      "Gateway": "10.118.76.1",
      "drives": [
        {
          "C": "100"
        },
        {
          "D": "50"
        }
      ]
    },
   {
     //can be n no of blocks
   }
  ]
}
```

Now Let's say block 1 has "site" value as "SGDC", "domain" as "DAPAC", "usagetype" as "Database Server", I will pass these values in another shell script(I ALREADY HAVE THIS Shell SCRIPT) as a parameter to generate a new value "SGDDAPACDS" and use this as a new key/value pair i.e "hostname": "SGDDAPACDB" and append it into block 1. Similarly, block 2 will have "hostname": "SGDEDAPACWS". So in the end, the JSON should look like this,

```
{
  "server_details": [
    {
      "seqNo": "01",
      "storage": "IBM",
      "datastore": "IDS-NR02",
      "cpu": 4,
      "site": "SGDC",
      "servertype": "Virtual Machine",
      "location": "Serangoon",
      "operatingsystem": "Linux",
      "systemcode": "BOC",
      "ram": 64,
      "databasesoftware": "MSSQL 2016",
      "usagetype": "Database Server",
      "environment": "Production_WithCustData",
      "domain": "DAPAC",
      "IPAddress": "10.117.254.25",
      "DNS": "10.118.76.34",
      "Gateway": "10.118.76.1",
      "drives": [
        {
          "C": "100"
        },
        {
          "D": "50"
        }
      ],
      "hostname": "SGDDAPACDS"            //new value
    },
    {
      "seqNo": "02",
      "storage": "HITACHI",
      "datastore": "HDS-NR02",
      "cpu": 4,
      "site": "SGDR",
      "servertype": "Virtual Machine",
      "location": "DRC",
      "operatingsystem": "Windows",
      "systemcode": "WOC",
      "ram": 64,
      "databasesoftware": "NA",
      "usagetype": "Web Server",
      "environment": "Production_NonCustData",
      "domain": "EDAPAC",
      "IPAddress": "10.117.254.26",
      "DNS": "10.118.76.34",
      "Gateway": "10.118.76.1",
      "drives": [
        {
          "C": "100"
        },
        {
          "D": "50"
        }
      ],
      "hostname": "SGDEDAPACWS"       //new value
    },
   {
     //can be n no of blocks
   }
  ]
}
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Thanks :) I have posted my answer. I was struggling with the quotes.

Answer (score 0):

I am able to resolve it via script. Basically, I was struggling with single quotes and double qoutes.

Below is the sample script

```
#!/bin/bash

if [ -f ./serv_details.json ]; 
then 
    arrayCount=`jq '.server_details | length' ./serv_details.json`
    for (( ac=0; ac<arrayCount; ac++ ))
    do 
        SITE=$(jq -r ".server_details[$ac].site" serv.json)
        LOC=$(jq -r ".server_details[$ac].environment" serv.json )
        SEQ=$(jq -r ".server_details[$ac].seqNo" serv.json)
        HO=`./hostsample.sh $SITE $LOC $SEQ`;   # It generates the concated Value
        echo $HO
        cat serv.json | jq '.server_details['"$ac"'] += {"hostname": "'"$HO"'"}' | sponge serv.json
        
    done
else
    echo "pls pass the value file"
fi
```

Then the output will be

```
{
  "server_details": [
    {
      "seqNo": "01",
      "storage": "IBM",
      "datastore": "IDS-G400-VS-DC-DE-T2-P01-NR02",
      "cpu": 4,
      "site": "SGDC",
      "servertype": "Virtual Machine",
      "location": "Serangoon",
      "operatingsystem": "Linux",
      "systemcode": "BOC",
      "ram": 64,
      "databasesoftware": "MSSQL 2016",
      "usagetype": "Database Server",
      "environment": "Production_WithCustData",
      "domain": "DAPAC",
      "IPAddress": "10.117.254.25",
      "DNS": "10.118.76.34",
      "Gateway": "10.118.76.1",
      "drives": [
        {
          "C": "100"
        },
        {
          "D": "50"
        }
      ],
      "hostname": "SGDS01"
    },
    {
      "seqNo": "02",
      "storage": "HITACHI",
      "datastore": "HDS-G400-VS-DC-DE-T2-P01-NR02",
      "cpu": 4,
      "site": "SGDR",
      "servertype": "Virtual Machine",
      "location": "DRC",
      "operatingsystem": "Windows",
      "systemcode": "WOC",
      "ram": 64,
      "databasesoftware": "NA",
      "usagetype": "Web Server",
      "environment": "Production_NonCustData",
      "domain": "DAPAC",
      "IPAddress": "10.117.254.26",
      "DNS": "10.118.76.34",
      "Gateway": "10.118.76.1",
      "drives": [
        {
          "C": "100"
        },
        {
          "D": "50"
        }
      ],
      "hostname": "SGDD02"
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: It's nice that you were able to solve your problem, but the script posted here has several examples of "worst practices", e.g. it would be better to call jq just twice or (depending on the details of hostsample.sh) maybe even once. Also you could use the -r option to avoid those calls to `tr`.

Comment: it was a quick solve haha, but I have removed the tr dependency. Thanks :)